# DateTime.ToString("d", cultureInfo) output differs between IIS and console app

Tags: c#, date, datetime, tostring, culture

I am using `DateTime.Now.ToString("d", new CultureInfo("nl-NL"))`.

In a local IIS web application, the output is correct:

```
22-7-2016
```

In a console application, the framework chooses the international/culture-invariant date notation:

```
2016-07-22
```

This is on the same machine, with the exact same code. I have placed a breakpoint, checked all input, and even tried running the commands in the immediate window at that point. In every situation, the console application gets it wrong.

Can anybody explain what causes the difference?

Comment: Can you include the full code of your console app that is doing this so we can confirm we are running the same code as you in our tests? My brief test shows no problems...

Comment: What is DateTime? The System.DateTime class does not have a static ToString method so the code you have given won't compile unless you have made a variable called DateTime or a ToString extension method.

Comment: `new CultureInfo("nl-NL", false)`

Comment: Apologies: `DateTime.Now.ToString~`

Comment: @PetSerAl `new CultureInfo("nl-NL", false)` did the trick! I believe Eli Arbel's (accepted) answer below explains why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIS and your console app run under different user accounts. If you've customized the date format (e.g. by using the Region control panel), the `CultureInfo` formatter will use that customization only in your account.

You can create a `CultureInfo` that disregards user settings:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL")
```

You reset the region settings for your account: Run > `intl.cpl` > Select the NL locale in the drop-down > Additional settings > Reset.

Comment: @EliArbel That explains it! I do have a different setting on my account, and PetSerAl's suggestion of using `new CultureInfo("nl-NL", false)` (i.e. userOverride=false) confirms your explanation, and allows us to counteract the behavior. If you would add this possibility to your answer, I will be happy to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Don't you agree it's strange that, by default, the user account setting wins *even though an explicit culture is given*?

Comment: @EliArbel The ToString() overload *without* a culture is intended to honor the user's culture. Passing an explicit culture is specifically intended for when the intended culture is *different* from the system user's culture (or the client's browser's culture, respectively, for IIS). So we pass a specific culture, and the system thinks it knows better and starts making assumptions as if we hadn't. That makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Timo It is not about `ToString`. `ToString` just format string using `IFormatProvider` you passed to it. And you pass `IFormatProvider` which respect user overrides. The thing is that constructor use `useUserOverride=true` by default. Maybe you should use `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL")`, which return cached read-only instance which does not respect user overrides.

Comment: @PetSerAl Ah, you're right, it's only about the `CultureInfo` itself. Good to know that `GetCultureInfo()` has different behavior than the constructor!

Answer (score -1):

I obtained same results in both console and web application with .NET 4.5 in VS 2012.

Could you try this?

```
yourDateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("nl-NL"));
```

Comment: Using an explicit format string beats the purpose of using "d".

Comment: Just for testing purposes. I said "Could you try..." to see what happens and identify the problem.

Comment: That's fine, but that's not an answer and doesn't prove anything.

Comment: Well, if he use that code and the output string is still wrong maybe some other code is changing culture settings. Best regards.

Comment: You're missing the point. You've just joined today, so you may want to read [answer]. If you post an answer, it must be an answer to the question. Debugging hints and other potentially helpful information that doesn't answer the question should be posted as comments to the question instead.

Comment: I have tried it just now. As expected, the explicit format always wins and results in the expected output.

Comment: Thanks for the info.